# Paste with if condition R

Tags: r

I am trying to write an `if` statement that pastes a character string in a new column, based on a range in another column. I have attempted modelling the statement off other SO answers but always get a warning message and incorrect outcome. Example data frame:

```
    Var1 Var2
    48   Na
    4    Na
    14   Na
    7    Na
    11   Na
    44   Na
    15   Na
    37   Na
    29   Na
    22   Na
    18   Na
    17   Na
    46   Na
    24   Na
    12   Na
```

Attempted script:

```
df$Var2 <- if(df$Var1 >=1 & df$Var1 <= 14) {
  paste("string1")
} else if (df$Var1 >=15 & df$Var1 <=35) {
  paste("string2")
} else {
  paste ("error")
}
```

Expected Outcome:

```
    Var1 Var2
    48   error
    4    string1
    14   string1
    7    string1
    11   string1
    44   error
    15   string2
    37   error
    29   string2
    22   string2
    18   string2
    17   string2
    46   error
    24   string2
    12   string1
```

When I run the above script,I get `df$Var2` filled with `error` I get the warning:

> 1: In if (df$Var1 >= 1 & df$Var1 <=  :   the condition has length > 1 and only the
> first element will be used

> 2: In if (df$Var1 >= 15 & df$Var1 <=  :   the condition has length > 1 and only the
> first element will be used

> 3: In if (df$Var1 > 35) { :   the condition
> has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

If anyone can provide some help as to the best way to progress, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: BTW, `paste("string")` is equivalent to `"string"`, that call to `paste` with a single, static string is a no-op.

Comment: The condition `df$Var1 >= 1 & df$Var1 <= 14` returns vector of logical values (`FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE`), but `if` can use only single logical value thus takes the very first one. That's why different function has to be used - either `ifelse` suggested by @Duck's answer or `mutate` from `dplyr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test conditions in that way, it is better to use `ifelse()`. The function `if()` works fine for individual values, that is why you got warnings because you wanted to apply it to a variable inside the dataframe. Here the code:

```
#Code
df$Var2 <- ifelse(df$Var1 >=1 & df$Var1 <= 14,'string1',
                  ifelse(df$Var1 >=15 & df$Var1 <=35,'string2','error'))
```

Other option can be using indexing based on conditions:

```
#Code 2
df$Var2 <- 'error'
#Conditions
cond1 <- df$Var1 >=1 & df$Var1 <= 14
cond2 <- df$Var1 >=15 & df$Var1 <=35
#Assign
df$Var2[cond1]<-'string1'
df$Var2[cond2]<-'string2'
```

Both options will produce same output:

```
df
   Var1    Var2
1    48   error
2     4 string1
3    14 string1
4     7 string1
5    11 string1
6    44   error
7    15 string2
8    37   error
9    29 string2
10   22 string2
11   18 string2
12   17 string2
13   46   error
14   24 string2
15   12 string1
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Var1 = c(48L, 4L, 14L, 7L, 11L, 44L, 15L, 37L, 
29L, 22L, 18L, 17L, 46L, 24L, 12L), Var2 = c("Na", "Na", "Na", 
"Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", 
"Na")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Or using `dplyr` as suggested by **@Dan** in comments:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df <- df %>% mutate(Var2=ifelse(Var1 >=1 & Var1 <= 14,'string1',
                                ifelse(Var1 >=15 & Var1 <=35,'string2','error')))
```

Comment: ifelse works perfectly. Many thanks. I need to work better on understanding when to use which statement

Answer (score 0):

We can use `case_when` with `between`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  
    mutate(Var2 = case_when(between(Var1, 1, 14)~ 'string1', 
          between(Var1, 15, 35)~ 'string2', TRUE ~ 'error'))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Var1 = c(48L, 4L, 14L, 7L, 11L, 44L, 15L, 37L, 
29L, 22L, 18L, 17L, 46L, 24L, 12L), Var2 = c("Na", "Na", "Na", 
"Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", 
"Na")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```